# dj-stripe DJSTRIPE_SUBSCRIBER_MODEL_REQUEST_CALLBACK conflict in settings.py

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

i'am trying to use dj-stripe library, but when i try to override DJSTRIPE_SUBSCRIBER_MODEL, the callback gone wrong.

Here is the model:

```
class GroupCompany(models.Model):
  owner = models.ForeignKey(Usuario, unique=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT )  
  def __unicode__(self):
    return '%s' % self.owner.get_full_name() 
  @property
  def email(self):
    return self.owner.email
```

Here the settings.py

```
DJSTRIPE_SUBSCRIBER_MODEL = 'base.GroupCompany'

def account_request_callback(request):
    """ Gets an organization instance from the id passed through ``request``"""
    return GroupCompany.objects.get(owner=request.user)

DJSTRIPE_SUBSCRIBER_MODEL_REQUEST_CALLBACK = account_request_callback
```

The problem is i can't import models in settings, because the aplications isn't loaded yet, but in the docs of dj.stripe, they say this is the way to do!!! im going crazy.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this is to import GroupCompany inside of the callback, so that it's loaded when the callback is executed, like so:

```
def account_request_callback(request):
    from ... import GroupCompany
    return GroupCompany.objects.get(owner=request.user)
```

-Alex